# tick size for US securities

Tags: market-microstructure, tick-data, tick

I there a source or way from which I can find out the minimum tick size for US securities at any point in time from 1970 until today?
I know that securities above \$1 have \$0.01 tick while those below \$1 have \$0.0001 tick since Jan 29, 2001 but how about before this time?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't find a definitive resource.

You can however past this together using sources on line.

https://www.finra.org/industry/tick-size-pilot-program

https://www.sec.gov/oiea/investor-alerts-bulletins/ia_ticksize.html

> I know that securities above \$1 have \$0.01 tick while those below \$1 have \$0.0001 tick since Jan 29, 2001 but how about before this time?

This is not really correct anymore due to the penny pilot tick rule put in place a few years ago on select symbols

The good news is that this doesn't change too often, if you search for penny pilot tick rule you'll find the majority of the symbols that traded at odd increments.

And warehousing has made this a bit muddier as sub penny price improvement can mean tickers that normally trade in penny increments actually get filled at non penny increments.